# Automatic login by url

Tags: php

With this script, I have to enter username and password to access the
 protected page, I would understand if it is possible via the address bar, login
 automatically, I tried

```
Http://example.org/index.php&myusername&mypassword
```

but I can not access it is possible to automatically login from address bar.

```
 <?php
    session_start();
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['pw'];

    if($username == "" or $password == ""){
    echo "Non puoi accedere senza Username o password";
    }else if($username == "" and $password == ""){
    echo "Non puoi accedere senza Username e password";
    }else{
    // configure your username and password
    if($username == "test" AND $password == "test"){
    echo "Benvenuto $username";
    echo "<a href='http://www.example.com'>Vai alla pagina</a>";
    }else{
    echo "Accesso negato, questo username non esiste";
    }
    }

function loggeduser($username){

}


?>
```

Comment: change `$_POST` to `$_REQUEST` and your url would be `http://example.org/index.php?username=test&pw=test`

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using $_REQUEST to request the variables in your address bar.

[PHP.net - $_REQUEST](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.request.php)

Answer (score 0):

Use the URL:

```
http://example.org/index.php?username=myusername&pw=mypassword
```

And update your script to

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $username = $_REQUEST['username'];
    $password = $_REQUEST['pw'];

    # continue as before
```

Comment: I made the above changes, changing $_POST with $_REQUEST, ma se immetto l'indirizzo http://example.org/index.php&username=myusername&pw=mypassword does not find that page, se http://example.org/index.php?username=myusername&pw=mypassword , brings me back to the login page

Comment: sorry typo in the url. it should be `http://example.org/index.php?username=myusername&pw=mypassword` .  note the ? right after the index.php and use a & between vars